# keep code organized using generic types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dynamic

I like to keep things separate when programming. That is one of the reasons why inheritance is important I believe.

I am using a dll file that consists of a class that I cannot modify. the dll file contains ClassA to illustrate my example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassA object1 = new ClassA();

        SomeMethod<ClassA>(object1 ); // error because " a does not implement ITemp"
    }

    static T SomeMethod<T>(T input)
        where T:ITemp // make sure input has a method MyCustomMethod
    {

        input.MyCustomMethod();

        return input;
    }
     // create this interface so that compiler does not complain when
     // calling MyCustomMethod in method above

    interface ITemp
    {
        void MyCustomMethod();
    }

}


// classA is a sealed class in a dll file that I cannot modify
public class ClassA
{
    public void MyCustomMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

why is there an error if object1  does implement ITemp inteface! object1  has the method MyCustomMethod()

I know I can use reflection to solve this but I like to keep my code clean. also I want to avoid using the dynamic type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ClassA doesn't implement the ITemp interface.  Just because it has a method with the same name and signature as the method in the ITemp interface doesn't mean it implements that interface.  The class would need to be declared to implement it explicitly.

Since you can't extend ClassA, the best thing I can think of would be to wrap it with an adapter type class:

```
public ClassB : ITemp {
    protected ClassA classAInstance;

    public ClassB( ClassA obj ) {
        classAInstance = obj;
    }

    public void MyCustomMethod() {
        classAInstance.MyCustomMethod();
    }
}
```

Then in your main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassA object1 = new ClassA();

    SomeMethod<ClassB>(new ClassB(object1));
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! That is a good thing to know. MyCustomMethod is not static therefore I would have to instantiate classAInstance in class b therefore I would have to create the appropriate constructors in classB. I guess I will have to use reflection this time. there are just 3 methods that I plan on using...

Comment: a small correction: the class *or one of its ancestor classes in the inheritance chain* would need to be declared to implement it explicitly.  Also, lest anyone be confused, the word "explicit" here is not related to the concept of the implicit vs. explicit implementation of interface *members*.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). C# does not support that in general outside of the `dynamic` type. ClassA would need to implement the interface, as you noted it doesn't and can not be made to be. You could wrap class with a proxy but that may or may not be a good idea.

Comment: C# does support duck typing in a few other places, notably foreach loops.

Comment: @phoog You are correct. Learn something new everyday [reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2007/07/18/ducknotation.aspx)

Comment: The reference also has an error.  It says that the `Current` property must return an object, but actually the `Current` property can return anything.  That's why the language designers chose to specify this duck typing: so, in a world before generics, we could write custom enumerators for value types, whose `Current` properties could return the unboxed value type, avoiding lots of boxing and unboxing overhead.